# Play framework store emails

Tags: email, playframework, playframework-1.x

Hi I have a requirement where we want to store emails in database before they are sent. I am currently using version 1.2.5. I want to leverage the Mail and MVC integration offered by play as the emails will have lot of dynamic content. Is there any way it can be done in play framework. Thanks anyone for giving some direction.

Comment: What kind of information do you want to store? Maybe you only want to store a few fields? Otherwise you can look at serializing the email and storing in in a log somewhere.

Comment: Please be a lot more specific about what to store where, and why

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to store the content (and don't care about the headers), then you can render the MVC View template to a String, and store that in a database. You would get the String as follows

```
String emailContent = TemplateLoader.load("pathToEmailView").render(args);
```

You just have to save this to a DB in the standard way before sending your email in the normal way.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Let me explain my usage a little bit. I am making use of MVC and mail integration as per play documentation. During registration my email template located at Account/welcome.html will be rendered and sent to the new user. Before this email is sent I want to store this rendered HTML content and store it in database for tracking purpose for CSR. Let me know if this explains the usage .

Comment: then the above solution should give you exactly what you need.

Comment: @SachinWalia since you are new to SO: you should edit your question to add those details rather then adding them as comment to one question if you want to be sure that everybody reads them! And yes Codemwnci solution produces exactly what you are asking for. Just store that in the DB.